# How to remove an ongoing notification programmatically?

Tags: android, web, notifications, whatsapp

I want to remove the ongoing notification from statusbar.For example whatsapp web notification when whatsapp web is active,usb debugging notification when device is connected to pc which are not removed when swipe.Is it possible or not?If its possible then please help me.Thank u.....

Comment: What have you tried so far with your code ? Please show us

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can dismiss a notification from statusbar. Just call `cancel()` for your notification ID.

Check out this link to learn more about removing Notifications: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Removing

Comment: I dont have notification id.I am trying to remove notification of another application.can i get notification id?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding only the notification icon on the notification bar (glance view without pulling down the slide bar to see the whole on going notifications), and its notif view still in the on going list, you can pay attention to the method setPriority of NotificationCompat.Builder.

In my case,the codeblock below saved my day!

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilderOnGoing = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=16) {
    mBuilderOnGoing.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN);
}
```

Hope it helps